# How to check the error logs in the Unittesting?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, babel-jest

I have a simple NodeJS application. And I'm writing some unittest using Jest for service methods. Below is one of the method,

```
import LogUtil from '../utils/logUtil.js'
const logger = LogUtil.getLogger();

export const bindTwoImagesIntoOne = async (firstImageText, secondImageText, imageWidth, imageHeight, textColor, imageSize) => {
try {
    const firstImageURL = getImageURL(firstImageText)
    const secondImageURL = getImageURL(secondImageText)
    const imageRequestParam = getImageRequstParam(imageWidth, imageHeight, textColor, imageSize)

    const firstImageResponse = await axios.get(firstImageURL, {responseType: ARRAY_BUFFER, ...imageRequestParam})
    logger.info('Successfully fetched the first image')

    const secondImageResponse = await axios.get(secondImageURL, {responseType: ARRAY_BUFFER, ...imageRequestParam})
    logger.info('Successfully fetched the second image')

    const firstImage = await Jimp.read(firstImageResponse.data);
    const secondImage = await Jimp.read(secondImageResponse.data);
    const combinedImage = new Jimp(firstImage.getWidth() + secondImage.getWidth(), Math.max(firstImage.getHeight(), secondImage.getHeight()));
    combinedImage.composite(firstImage, 0, 0);
    combinedImage.composite(secondImage, firstImage.getWidth(), 0);
    
    const fileOut = join(process.cwd(), IMAGE_FOLDER.concat('/').concat(SAVED_IMAGE_NAME));
    await combinedImage.writeAsync(fileOut);
    logger.info('Successfully generated the binded image')
} catch (e) {
    logger.error('Failed to bind the images!')
    logger.error(e)
}
```

}

And the unittest I wrote is below,

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Jimp from 'jimp';
import {bindTwoImagesIntoOne} from '../services/bindImageService.js'
import LogUtil from '../utils/logUtil.js'

jest.mock('axios');
jest.mock('jimp');

const logger = LogUtil.getLogger();

describe('bindTwoImagesIntoOne', () => {
   test('should log error when fetching images fails', async () => {
      const mockError = new Error('Failed to fetch image');

   axios.get.mockRejectedValueOnce(mockError);
   const errorMock = jest.spyOn(logger, 'error');
   await bindTwoImagesIntoOne(firstImageText, secondImageText, imageWidth, imageHeight, textColor, imageSize);
   expect(errorMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
   expect(errorMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Failed to bind the images!');
   expect(errorMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockError);

   errorMock.mockRestore();
});
});
```

And the unittest is failing with below error. What may be the reason for it?

```
Expected number of calls: 2
Received number of calls: 0

> 60 |     expect(logger.error).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
```

You can see the in the catch block there are 2 error logs, But why it says 0??